# Performant Haskell hashed structure.

Tags: haskell, hashmap, hashtable

I am writing program that does *alot* of table lookups. As such, I was perusing the Haskell documentation when I stumbled upon `Data.Map` (of course), but also `Data.HashMap` and `Data.Hashtable`. I am no expert on hashing algorithms and after inspecting the packages they all seem really similar. As such I was wondering:

1: what are the major differences, if any?

2: Which would be the most performant with a high volume of lookups on maps/tables of ~4000 key-value pairs?

Comment: You might be also interested in [this blog post](http://gregorycollins.net/posts/2011/06/11/announcing-hashtables). It shows a lot of interesting figures and compares different approaches to hash tables in Haskell. The post comes to the eventual conclusion, that you need impurity in order to make proper hashtables work fast.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman Folks on SO often can provide insight that you could not discover on your own. For example, the author of the library or someone familiar could stumble upon the question and explain obscure configuration options, or a way to tweak something. Futhermore, someone could recommend a fourth option `SuperHashMap`. Finally, someone else in my position in the future can see this question and learn from it.

Comment: In general, don't identify code by module name.  In the Haskell universe module names collide.  For example, when you say `Data.HashMap` I am guessing you're talking about the `hashmap` package, which has worse performance than the `unordered-containers` HashMap implementation that I would suggest you use.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thank you for that link. That, combined with @mergeconflict 's answer has convinced me to try the cuckoo implementation in the `hashtables` package. Also, thank you @ThomasM.DuBuisson, I am still new to Haskell and need tips like these!

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson It's not the case that `unordered-containers` is faster than `hashmap` for everything.  I use `HashMap` from the former and `HashSet` from the latter for best performance in my particular application.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> 1: What are the major differences, if any?

- `Data.Map.Map` is a balanced binary tree internally, so its time complexity for lookups is O(log n).  I believe it's a "[persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)" data structure, meaning it's implemented such that mutative operations yield a new copy with only the relevant parts of the structure updated.
- `Data.HashMap.Map` is a `Data.IntMap.IntMap` internally, which in turn is implemented as Patricia tree; its time complexity for lookups is O(min(n, W)) where *W* is the number of bits in an integer.  It is also "persistent.". New versions (>= 0.2) use hash array mapped tries. According to the documentation: "Many operations have a average-case complexity of O(log n). The implementation uses a large base (i.e. 16) so in practice these operations are constant time."
- `Data.HashTable.HashTable` is an actual hash table, with time complexity O(1) for lookups.  However, it is a mutable data structure -- operations are done in-place -- so you're stuck in the `IO` monad if you want to use it.

> 2: Which would be the most performant with a high volume of lookups on maps/tables of ~4000 key-value pairs?

The best answer I can give you, unfortunately, is "it depends."  If you take the asymptotic complexities literally, you get O(log 4000) = about 12 for `Data.Map`, O(min(4000, 64)) = 64 for `Data.HashMap` and O(1) = 1 for `Data.HashTable`.  But it doesn't really work that way...  You have to try them in the context of your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the IO monad at this point anyways due to lots of file IO. The result of all of these IO and hash lookups is yielded from a coroutine, so it'll be easy to escape IO afterwards. I think I'll give Data.HashTable a shot and see how it does. Thank you very much for your help~

Comment: Sure thing; also check out `Data.HashTable.ST` from the [hashtables](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables) package, noted first above by @FUZxxl.

Comment: the time complexity `O(min(n, W))` for a Patricia tree doesn't seem right ... might as well use a list then, no?

Comment: oops, I'm wrong, the worst case is linear. Also, the Patricia tree comment is in Data.HashMap.Strict (type HashMap) it seems ...

Comment: @mergeconflict  Hi, where can i read the internal implemenation of data structures  like hashmap in detail in haskell?

Comment: @rohitwtbs, you can checkout most sources in either hackage or github. For example, [unordered-containers-0.2.10.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.10.0)

Answer (score 14):

The obvious difference between `Data.Map` and `Data.HashMap` is that the former needs keys in `Ord`, the latter `Hashable` keys. Most of the common keys are both, so that's not a deciding criterion. I have no experience whatsoever with `Data.HashTable`, so I can't comment on that.

The APIs of `Data.HashMap` and `Data.Map` are very similar, but `Data.Map` exports more functions, some, like `alter` are absent in `Data.HashMap`, others are provided in strict and non-strict variants, while `Data.HashMap` (I assume you meant the hashmap from [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers)) provides lazy and strict APIs in separate modules. If you are using only the common part of the API, switching is really painless.

Concerning performance, `Data.HashMap` of [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) has pretty fast lookup, last I measured, it was clearly faster than `Data.IntMap` or `Data.Map`, that holds in particular for the (not yet released) HAMT branch of [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers). I think for inserts, it was more or less on par with `Data.IntMap` and somewhat faster than `Data.Map`, but I'm a bit fuzzy on that.

Both are sufficiently performant for most tasks, for those tasks where they aren't, you'll probably need a tailor-made solution anyway. Considering that you ask specifically about lookups, I would give `Data.HashMap` the edge.

Comment: Be _sure_ you are talking about the same `Data.Hashmap`.  Unordered-containers was measureably faster than other package's `HashMap` offerings, last I checked.

Comment: Good point. I had completely forgotten there was a previous `Data.HashMap`.

Comment: In 2015, there isn't anymore Data.HashMap in base. There is one in the hashtables package

Answer (score 3):

`Data.HashTable`'s documentation now says "use the [hashtables](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables) package". There's a nice blog post explaining why hashtables is a good package [here](http://gregorycollins.net/posts/2011/06/11/announcing-hashtables). It uses the ST monad.

Comment: The `hashtables` package uses the `ST` monad not the `State` monad.

Comment: right, `ST` is just the transformer (i.e. useful) version of `State`.

Comment: No it's not. There's a huge conceptual difference. The `ST` monad carries the state at the type level while the `State` monad carries the state at the value level :)